# Schema.org microdata for realestate platform

Tags: schema.org

I'm working on a website that is a realestate portal, showing items from multiple agencies.

I have two kind of pages :

- listings, from global (global search) or agency specific (agency landing page) data
- item details

Each agency can rent or sell items, there is also rental vacation but for the moment I would like to focus only on rent/sell.

After lot of searches, I'm always a little lost on how implementing microdata in the best way...

I saw that Product with "offers" as aggregateOffer can be used to give some informations on the page (number of items, low and high prices, currency), maybe like this :

```
<script type='application/ld+json'>
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "Product",
    "name": "Items to sell at [locality]",
    "offers": {
        "@type": "AggregateOffer",
        "priceCurrency": "EUR",
        "lowPrice": "195000",
        "highPrice": "790000",
        "offerCount": "14",
    }
}
</script>
```

But in this case, I can't show informations for each item on the page...

In the same way, I know that Appartment / House /SingleFamilyResidence schema exists, but I can link it to an Organisation, because it doesn't contains, either it's parents, any way to link an accomodation to a Person / Organization...

What I would like to do is the following, but maybe it's not the correct way to give some microdata for SEO...

On listing and item details pages (searches results for example) I would like to use an accomodation schema (appartment/house/singleFamilyResidence) to describe each item, and related to an Organisation or maybe LocalBusiness / Broker ??
And possibly use "Product" to give price and other "offer" informations ?

It's not easy to find some examples, and there is a lot of schema available... If anyone can point to me a correct/logic way to add microdata for this kind of data, it would be very helpful, because I'm stuck on the structure and hierarchy to use.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.